# Press the Back Browser button loosing the previous page state

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, jquery

I am creating a .net application where on the main page I am creating some text boxes dynamically.

```
<div>
Enter how much pets you have : <input type="text" id="amount" />
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="btn" />
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
{
   $("#btn").click(function()
   {
      var i = 0;
      for(i = 0; i <= $("#amount").val(); i++)
      {
         $("#Names").append("<p>Name " + i.toString() + ":<input id='name" + i.toString() + " type='text' class='nameInput'/>");
      }
   });

   $("#SubmitNames").click(function()
   {
      $.getJSON("names.aspx",$(".nameInput"),function(data)
      {
          if(data.Status == "Success")
          {
              window.location.href = "step2.aspx";
          }
      });
   });
});
</script>
</div>
```

When the user is clicking the submit names it is redirected to step2.aspx

Till here everything is working fine!

The problem starts when the user will go back ("clicks the back browser button") the whole previous status is lost.

The user must enter all again all names.

I think I am missing something. I need to do the data transmittion via AJAX.

Can you help me? What do you suggest?

I am using .NET c# VS2008

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Ben Almans [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/). It is very good. It utilises the hash tag to persist changes into the browser history cache. UI tabs demo [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-jquery-ui-tabs/).

Comment: @Mystere Man - not sure where you heard that, but it is wrong. (Tested with jQuery 1.3.2, 1.4.1, 1.4.2 in Internet Explorer 6-8, Firefox 2-3.7, Safari 3-4, Chrome 4-5, Opera 9.6-10.1, Mobile Safari 3.1.1.)

Comment: From your link: "jQuery BBQ leverages the HTML5 hashchange event to allow simple, yet powerful bookmarkable #hash history."

Comment: @Mystere Man - so ie6 is html5 compliant;) - It uses fallbacks for non html5 browsers....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is going to work.  When you click the back button, it reloads the page from cache.  That cache does not include changes you have made via javascript.  So it's reloading the base page, then re-executing the javascript, creating a brand new set of empty controls.

Your best is to save the values submitted to a hidden field (probably using json) then have a "go back" button on your next form, then reloading your controls state if the hidden field contains data.

EDIT:

Since you're not submitting anything, perhaps you can modify your "names.aspx" to return the names entered if you do not pass any data.  Then in your first step you can do an ajax call to retrieve any names that might be set, doing nothing if no names are returned.

I should note, however, that using GET in this manner is highly unusual, and according to the HTTP specification get should not change the state of an object (which you seem to be doing).

Comment: it makes sense. Ok let's say I change the submit button to <asp:button /> how can I submit this text boxes values? How can I read them server side (since these textboxes are generated with javascript)

Comment: even with a hidden field you cant hold them by posting them true ajax.. because you have to set it aswel with ajax so the browser will forget it aswel
@David Bonnici.. If im right you read it here: ` $.getJSON("names.aspx"`

Comment: Sorry, just realized that you're not actually submitting anything, you're just calling another page with the names as querystring values.  Editing my answer.

Comment: @Mystere Man, your edit answer will still not work.. even if you return anything from name.aspx your still doing it in ajax.. If your POSTING something or save something to a session or cookie you will be able to get something like that back.. 

NOTE: your browser back button only caches your browser page(originale HTML) and anything you post..

Comment: @Tricker - Yes, my solution would work.  You're not understanding it.  When he uses the getJSOM call the first time, it returns nothing because there are no values sent to it.  When he clicks the submit button, it posts the ajax to names.aspx and saves the state.  When you click back, it queries names.aspx again and this time it returns values because they have been set in a previous call, and he can then populate the dynamic controls from that.

Comment: @Mystere Man, so basicly your saying when you go back it does the ajax post again? and can u show/explain to me how a browser saves the same ajax post values(so the ajax post being handled as a normal POST in this case GET)? or do i miss something?

Comment: @Tricker - I'm not saying it's a good solution, i'm just trying to show how he can make his existing design do what he wants.  He is using the get to post values to another page via querystring.  I assume that page is storing or doing something with those values.  If so, then that page can be modified to return those values if no querystring is sent.  That get (with an empty querystring) can be used to repopulate the fields.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you add a input field by ajax.. The browser dont know what you post
For example when you `POST` and you get to the next page and go back you will get all given information in the fields before you post it..

I think even when you cache it, it doenst work.. because for the browser the amount of input field doesnt exists..

So what you can try is is instead off using `$.getJSON` try it with `$.ajax({ cache: true })` little example [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-json-ajax-caching/)..

if thats not working i would suggest to set a cookie and check it if there is a cookie when loading the page.

goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Did you inspect the HTTP header's expiration/caching settings that the server sends to the client?

This usually has an influence on whether the page is reloaded or being pulled from the cache when user clicks the "Back" button.

Comment: the browser is reading from the cache but the HTML is the original one.